# ActionScript 3 gotoAndPlay error

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseover

I've got a simple AS3 script that jumps to a new frame when a button (mc_rollbutton) is moused over:

```
mc_rollbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage3);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(134);
}
```

When I play the movie, it's outputting this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at bc_comp_03_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

Do I have the MovieClip(root) syntax wrong? Frame 134 is on the main timeline and I get the same error if I omit MovieClip(root) and just use `gotoAndPlay(134);`.

Thanks for any help you can throw my way!

Joe

Comment: If the code is on the main timeline you could use this.gotoAndPlay(134). Double check that it's not the button that's undefined. Do you have a button on the stage with an instance name of mc_rollbutton?

Comment: I do have a mc_rollbutton on the stage, but what seems to be causing the problem is not introducing it until frame 134. If I put it on frame 1 and hide it, the error goes away - so I guess that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment above, I discovered that the error occurred when my movie clip was not on the first frame of the movie, where the main ActionScript code was. I copied the MC to frame 1, turned off the Visible option and it all worked. Hope this helps someone else.

- Joe

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem a few times. I have searched my notes, but i cant find the right thing now so i will just state few options. But again if anything is not working pls reply and i will search my other notes when i woke up, becouse i know i have writen that case somewhere.

For now try with with:

```
function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //option 1
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(134);
    //option 2
    MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay(134);
    //option 3
    var mc:MovieClip = this.parent as MovieClip;
    mc.gotoAndPlay(134);
}
```

well i hope something will help, didn't open flash for a year now so fingers crossed (: